# RTSP to Flash Media Server

Tags: rtsp, rtmp, flash-media-server

I have a live RTSP h.264 720p 8Mb stream that I need to get to my streaming provider's Flash Media Server.   The only way that I currently have to stream to my provider's FMS is through Adobe's "Flash  Media Live Encoder" Which works well enough with our SD analog capture card for live streaming.
I can open and re-stream the RTSP stream  with VLC however VLC will not stream RTMP to the Flash Media Server.
Any thoughts on how to do this without going through the analog hole?